# ReplaceAll regex pattern in a string scala

Tags: scala

```
val test = "0|0.0|0;|0"
```

Hello , I am trying to replaceAll in the above string, only the "0.0" and "0;"

```
 scala> test.replaceAll("0.0", "")
 res1: String = .;|0
```

the approach did not work, or the regex

```
scala> val regex = "0.0".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = 0.0

scala> regex.replaceAllIn(test,"")
res0: String = .;|0
```

Please let me know if there is any simple way to replaceAll in the string, the result which I am looking for is

```
 Result that I am looking for
 "0|||0"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to OR the 2 options that can follow the leading zero.

```
"0|0.0|0;|0".replaceAll("0(\\.0|;)", "")
//res0: String = 0|||0
```